# Обособление приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли  в ряде приложений перед именем собственным слова "любимую нашу арматурщицу" рассматривать, как приложение, имеющее дополнительное обстоятельственное значение и соответственно - надо ли ставить после него запятую?

"... петербурженку, любимую нашу арматурщицу, N.N."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По правилу, приложение, стоящее перед определяемым словом - именем собственным, не обособляется ( великий русский поэт А.С.Пушкин))

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос представляется не таким однозначным, так как здесь мы имеем два приложения, отнесенные к имени собственному, а такие приложения могут быть однородными или неоднородными, ряд может обособляться или нет.

В частности, ОДНОРОДНЫЙ ряд приложений обычно не обособляется, если он относится к имени собственному и стоит перед ним, например: "Учитель военной прогимназии, коллежский регистратор Лев Пустяков обитал рядом с другом своим, поручиком Леденцовым".

А вот еще более сложное оформление (обособленный ряд из двух приложений между НАР + СОБСТВ): "Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живёт один мне знакомый человек, молодой помещик, гвардейский офицер в отставке, Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин".